# QGIS Plot Layout SVG in HTML Element - Size Problem

Tags: qgis, layouts, svg, plot

I would like to use an SVG in the QGIS Plot Layout. I am using an HTML Element to display a simple SVG, sized using mm units.

The SVG does not seem to display with the desired dimensions. I have removed the margin and padding using a user-defined CSS, but the SVG (green background), does not fill the HTML element (blue background). the SVG shuld be 100 mm wide/high but is only about 90mm.

I have also tried with `width:100mm;height:100mm` and `width:100%;height:100%` which did not alter the result.

In the screenshot you can see the SVG and CSS settings.

Does anyone have any tips?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not neccesarily a QGIS issue - I have learned more about SVG and CSS. Units in 'mm' do not necessarily translate to the screen as expected.

I have obtained the desired result by using a **unitless** SVG, with a `viewBox` which defines the image extents to match the contents (see image below). The `height` and `width` are not set. The svg is embedded in the html and fills the QGIS Template nicely - which is set at 100mm width and height. I was over-complicating in my first attempt. This solution may help someone in the future.

[image: Working Solution]